# toArray() method of Vector<> class

Tags: java, arrays, vector, dynamic-arrays

A [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)  may contain objects of different types. Does calling the [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#toArray--) method return an `Object[]` array or an array of specific objects (Eg. `Integer`, `Double`)? I'm guessing it does not return specific object arrays since an array can have objects of one type only.

Is there any way of creating multiple object specific arrays depending on the object types contained in a `Vector`?

Comment: You'd actually hope that a `Vector` only contains your parameterized type (e.g. `Vector<String>`).  [The Javadoc on Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#toArray()) will also satisfy your concern around `toArray`.

Comment: Using a `Vector` for elements of different types when the differences *matter* probably indicates bad design. A vector is usually supposed to be a list of similar things that you want to process in bulk. If you're using it as a "bag of odd stuff" you should probably re-think your design.

Comment: While I agree that it's likely not the best design, I want to point out that even if the compiler doesn't know about it, the Vector still contain the specific elements. It's *just* that the compiler can't guarantee you thats all thats in there. You lose static compile checking (which is a thing you shouldn't throw away easily), but it still works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `Vector` and any `Collection` object  have 2 methods : `toArray()` which returns `Object[]` and `toArray(T[])` which you have to provide an array of the correct type.

If you have a Collection of `Integer` this will work:

```
Vector<Integer> vector = ...
 Integer[] myInts = vector.toArray(new Integer[vector.size()]);
```

Note that I created an array of the size of the vector.  This isn't actually required but will speed things up since otherwise Java will have to use reflection to figure out the type and create an array of the correct size.

If your Collection has a mixture of different incompatiable types, and you provide an array that can't be used to store them all, the JVM will throw an `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` at *runtime* when you call `toArray(array[])`

```
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<>();
    vector.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
    vector.add(Double.valueOf(3.14));

    vector.toArray(new Integer[vector.size()]); //<-- throws ArrayStoreException
```

However, using an array of objects that all the objects in the vector are compatiable with is OK.

This will work since both `Integer` and `Double` extend `Number`

```
Number[] myNumbers = vector.toArray(new Number[vector.size()]);
```

Comment: What exactly would happen if I specified toArray(Integer[]) and my vector contained objects of both Integer and Double types? Would the compiler catch this error during compilation or during run-time?

Answer (score 1):

Because you can only return 1 object from the method, the way to do this would be to create a [ManyMap](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/OneToManyMapCollection.htm), indexing the Class of each object with a list/array of the objects that are of that class